# Server Error in '/Remote' Application

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2

Have just got my anywhere access setup on my server 2012 R2 standard server and I am now facing an issue where i get an error everytime i try to log into it from anywhere be that on the server, on a pc on the same network or on a pc outside of the network the server gives out a different error to the two PCs that i tried please see below for both errors. Hoping someone can help me solve this.
[Error from computers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPtlH.png)
[Server Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K1b8P.png)

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, ended up being had the **wrong version of the .NET framework**, silly me.